# Ask how to automatically grab the word from the array list

Tags: python, python-2.7

As title ,I web crawler the diigo , and have many list, I become the list to the set().Like this:

```
data = [ ['spanish', 'web2.0', 'e-learning', 'education', 'social', 'spain', 'tools', 'learning', 'google', 'e-learning2.0'],   ['education', 'technology', 'learning', 'classroom', 'students', 'web2.0'], ['education'],  ['technology'] ]
```

And doing something calculate

```
search_table = {}

for i, tag_list in enumerate(data):
    for tag in tag_list:
        if tag not in search_table:
            search_table[tag] = set()
        search_table[tag].add(i)  

# How many people have `technology`?
print(len(search_table["technology"]))
# How many people have `education`?
print(len(search_table["education"]))
# How many people have both `technology`, `education`?
print(len(search_table["technology"] & search_table["education"]))
```

data have many tags, i want to do this ->print(len(search_table["**technology**"]))<- **technology can auto change next world** like classroom.

i realy don't konw how to do,i only think is

```
for u in user_data:

   print u
```

but how to add the world to print(len(search_table[" **u** "]))

sincerely bob

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're saying. Can you try to rephrase your question? Maybe show some sample input and expected output that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @TimPietzcker sorry i cahnge question , i hope you konw what i say !

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you mean. You were nearly there:

```
user_data = ["technology", "classroom"]
for u in user_data:
    print(len(search_table[u]))
```

will first print the number of items in `search_table["technology"]` and then print the number of items in `search_table["classroom"]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with lists, you access elements of the list using numbers so you will not need to change the word 'code'. You would merely access it like this:

```
>>> user_data = ['code','java','learn']
>>> user_data[0]
'code'
>>>
```

Generally, when you're accessing elements like user_data["code"], it's because you're accessing keys of a dictionary like so:

```
>>> user_data = {'code':'java, python, ruby'}
>>> user_data['code']
'java, python, ruby'
```

Depending on how you store the information will affect how you're accessing that stored information. Considering you have user data, you will probably want to store them in dictionaries in lists like:

```
[
  {'name': 'bob', 'code': 'java, python', 'school':'StackOU'},
  {'name': 'bobina', ...
]
```

You'd access bob's coding skills like:

```
>>> user_data = [
...       {'name': 'bob', 'code': 'java, python', 'school':'StackOU'},
...     ]
>>> user_data[0]['code']
'java, python'
```

Comment: ATLUS  thank your answer!!  i change the question , do you know to do this?